# SUGON T3602 soldering station heating problem

Tags: soldering-iron-station

I received SUGON T3602 soldering station that needs fixing :

When using the handle jack marked c210 - the tip reaches the set temperature and stays there
But when using the jack marked as c115 (both handles) overshoot the set temperature by about 150 degree C on the readout and then just go crazy up and down  finially after 3 seconds the device shuts that handle down and the temperature drops

When i measured the temperature at the tip
The c210 jack did got the tip to the right temperature (after calibration) while the c115 jack reached max of 150 degree C

Did anyone had this problem?
How do i fix it ?

Edit: added pics from the inside
https://ibb.co/jgPvgsc
https://ibb.co/M1q396f

I bypassed the series resistor in  cable and fixed fixed the connecotr to the board  that connects the C115 jacks ground

Now the temperature rise same in both handles (though why did someone put it there?) Although when calibrating the good jack (C210) i had to rise 20 degree and it was constant no matter what temperature i set it to
On the other hand the (C115) jack had different calibrations needed for each temerature

Now im having other issue - when i use the good jack and try to heatup some solder on a board (relativly thin trace of DIP chip) - it indecates about 20% load and takes about 3-5 seconds to heatup!!

While the bad jack takes at least 5 seconds to start melting anything and very poorly - the load indecationan stays at about 2% ...

Comment: what are C115 and c210 jacks?

Comment: the description of the problem is inconsistent ... in one paragraph you say that the soldering iron overheats by 150 degree ... in the other paragraph you say that the soldering iron only reaches 150 degrees

Comment: @jsotola The first mention of 150 is for the readout, the second is his measured temperature of the tip.

Comment: Is one of the handles marked C115?  or are they both C210?

Comment: c115 and c210 are JBC cartridge sizes. Many generic soldering stations use cartridges from better known manufacturers, and often support multiple types.

Comment: @jsotola the sugon t3602 soldering station has 2 handle one is made identical to jbc C115 tips handle and the other is fit for jbc C210 tips  - you can read more in jbc website for your second comment as evildemonic sayed one paragaraph i was talking about the readout and the other about the acctual measured temerature

Comment: @evildemonic one handle is marked as C115 and other marked as C210 ... from different reviews on the internet both work from 22V transformer so i tryed both outputs (jacks) with both handles